# MindSphere URL Access

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, mindsphere

I am trying to access Mindsphere URL with Java Code. I am getting 403 forbidden error while doing it. While I am able to hit other POST URL's for other sites, Mindsphere URL is getting blocked by same piece of Java Code. Can someone help?
What am i missing in my Code?

restTemplate.exchange(*,*,*,TimeseriesData.class) is line giving error

Answer (score 0):

MindSphere demands a authorization header with a JWT Token, if you call directly the API. I guess you have an Developer account in MindSphere. Try Application credentials in the Developer cockpit. With that credentials you can get a bearer token with an oauth flow.

If not just ping me again.

See Exampel with OK HTTP

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "grant_type=client_credentials");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://questdev.piam.eu1.mindsphere.io/oauth/token")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache,no-cache")
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .addHeader("Postman-Token", "24126d6b-3461-48fb-9060-6fd005804227")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: URL url = new URL("https://questdev.piam.eu1.mindsphere.io/oauth/token");
 HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url
         .openConnection();
 connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
 connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
     "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         String user = "narasimharao.vk@quest-global.com";
         String password = "Valued@123";
         String authValue = user + ":" + password;     connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization",
                             "Basic "+authValue);
 connection.setDoOutput(true);

Comment: above standalone code returning 401. but I want it to return 200 with access token.

Comment: Kindly help. wat am i missing

Comment: I'm Missing the grant_type. And is the authValue Based64 encoded?
I have added an example to my recent post

Comment: But how to get Postman Token? Other things I understood. Yes I will include the grant type as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Postman token is not needed. This comes only if you use the program postman to do our calls like soap ui